# How to extract text before and after a keyword and date

Tags: python, pandas, text

I would like to seperate the authors name, the domain and the date out of a dataframe column.

While 
.split(" in ")
works well to seperate the authors name on the left, I also want to seperate the domain and the date, which are not seperated through a space sign.

```py
from pandas import DataFrame

Cars = {'Details': ['Daniel Jacobs in HackeMoon.comJul 31, 2017','Wil Zelk in websiteabc.deJan 28','Wil Zelk in anotherwebsite.chJan 28, 2019'],
        }

df = DataFrame(Cars,columns= ['Details'])

print(df)
```

```
df = df.Details.str.split(" in ", expand=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `DataFrame.str.extract` for this in combination with a regex:

```
df['Details'].str.extract(r'(?P<author>.*?) in (?P<url>.*)(?P<date>[A-Z].*)', expand=True)
```

This yields:

```
          author                url          date
0  Daniel Jacobs      HackeMoon.com  Jul 31, 2017
1       Wil Zelk      websiteabc.de        Jan 28
2       Wil Zelk  anotherwebsite.ch  Jan 28, 2019
```

To separate the strings I make use of the following assumptions:

- the name and the url are separated by " in "
- the first character (and only the first character) of the date is an upper case letter (so the last upper case character in the string marks the first character of the date part)

Comment: Great response. Many thanks for taking the time. Your assumptions are spot on and this works very well.

Comment: You may are  also able to help me for the cases, where there is not always a url given. So in the case of: 
```python
Cars = {'Details': ['Daniel JacobsJul 31, 2017','Wil Zelk in websiteabc.deJan 28','Wil Zelk in anotherwebsite.chJan 28, 2019'],
        }

df = DataFrame(Cars,columns= ['Details'])
print(df)
```

Comment: This here should work as long as you have a date in each line: `df['Details'].str.extract(r'(?P<author>.*?)(?: in ){0,1}(?P<url>\S*?)\s*(?P<date>[A-Z][^A-Z]*?$)', expand=True)`.

Comment: The `\S*` in the url pattern just uses the fact, that URLs normally don't contain spaces (it matches all characters except for whitespaces).

Comment: Again your answers are very helpful!